# Drawing a bordered path with sharp corners in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drawing, java-2d

I am working on an application that displays GPS tracks on a map.  I want to draw the track as a colored path of arbitrary thickness.  I found the `GeneralPath` class which seems to do just what I want.  However, I want the colored path to also have a black border.  I couldn't find anything about how to add a border to a path, so I came up with a quick hacky solution of drawing a thick black path first, and then drawing a thin colored path on top.

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PathBorder {
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PathBorder window = new PathBorder();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public PathBorder() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                GeneralPath path;
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.5f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                path = new GeneralPath();
                path.moveTo(0, 0);
                path.lineTo(100, 100);
                path.lineTo(200, 100);
                path.lineTo(100, 80);
                g2d.draw(path);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.draw(path);
            }
        };
        frame.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Here is a pic (taken from the SSCCE) to highlight my problem.  See the red circle below, notice how the outside border has a gap in it.  I want that gap to be filled in so the border is continuous.

[image]

Here are some actual screenshots from my app of a real track:

[image]

If you look closely at the sharp hairpin turn in the lower right of the track, you'll see that the border gets lost briefly... the detailed pic below makes it more clear.

[image]

I am not sure exactly how to fix this, but I'm open to suggestions, either keeping with the `GeneralPath` strategy, or using a different idea entirely.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hard-code the data with the points.

Comment: BTW - I *think* I understand the problem, but AFAIU there is no solution if you wanted a black line splitting the road(s) on the lower right of the picture.  The problem is that the two are so close, and the stroke so thick, that visually they are going to overlap.  To split that with a black line would make each road look like a 'lane' or one way street.  I think the way to get a better (and still understandable) rendering is to decrease the thickness of the stroke.  But if the user zooms out enough, they kind of expect details to merge.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I will post a SSCCE momentarily.  But to respond to your second comment... my issue is not the lack of a "splitting line"... it is that if you follow the **outside** border around the hairpin corner, you'll see that it has a break in it.

Comment: Setting some of the rendering hints may help.  Try setting KEY_STROKE_CONTROL to VALUE_STROKE_PURE and try setting KEY_RENDERING to VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately neither of those helped.  I will try playing with some of the other hints though, maybe one will do it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson SSCCE is up now, along with another picture to try to be more clear.

Comment: I am still open to other suggestions, but it seems like setting the Cap/Join styles for my BasicStroke both to "round" may be a viable solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Experiment with the `cap` and `join` parameters for a better effect.  E.G.

[image: PathBorder]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PathBorder {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    PathBorder window = new PathBorder();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public PathBorder() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            GeneralPath path;

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                BasicStroke s = new BasicStroke(
                        5.5f, 
                        BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, 
                        BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
                g2d.setStroke(s);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                if (path==null) {
                    path = new GeneralPath();
                    path.moveTo(0, 0);
                    path.lineTo(100, 100);
                    path.lineTo(200, 100);
                    path.lineTo(100, 80);
                }
                g2d.draw(path);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.draw(path);
            }
        };
        frame.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured if you didn't notice that I'd save you the knowledge that I wasted your time. :-P  But I really appreciate the help regardless, and glad you enjoyed playing.